# Most scalable distributed consensus mechanism based on message complexity?

Tags: complexity

One of the most challenges in distributed consensus mechanisms is both time complexity and message complexity.

For example, PBFT message complexity is `O(n^2)` that means that it is only scalable to tens of nodes. Thus, classical BFT (Byzantine Fault Tolerant) consensus mechanisms are not scalable to the large networks.

Nevertheless, I am looking for the most scalable BFT consensus  among all.

In other words, is there a distributed BFT consensus with less than `O(n^2)` message complexity?

**P.S.** If you think that there a better and more relevant **Stack Exchange** site to bring up this question, please let me know.

Comment: You might try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Richard , OK, I asked it here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/131203/107271